# Android storing cache of api response control http->cache (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, fetch

I don't want to store API response but headers are not working as expected in react-native Android.

Headers added in fetch request:

```
 let headers = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  cache: 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
  Pragma: 'no-cache',
  Expires: '0',
};
```

Android is Storing Apis response

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this issue, adding the header below solved it for me:

`"Cache-Control": 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'`

I believe the no-store is what you need.
Here's a link to some useful docs explaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

looks like you've just added cache rather than Cache-Control